# How create a regex for parsing a list grouped by keywords

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having a very bad time trying to make a regex to work. I would like to parse a list like this

```
Teacher teacher name
Class class name
student full name 1
student full name 2

Teacher teacher name
Class class name
student full name 1
student full name 2
Class class name
student full name 1
student full name 2

Teacher teacher name
Class class name
student full name 1
student full name 2
```

I want to retrieve a list of groups containing a teacher, each teacher contains some classes, and each class contains some students.
The words "Teacher" and "Class" are the keywords. If the line is none of this, than it will be a student of a previous class.

The closest I've got is `Teacher\t(.+?)\t*$(^Class\t(.+?)\t*$(^.+\t*$)*)*` without success. But it does not match the inner contents of a "Teacher Group"

I always do have an option for writing a for loop, but I really want to learn how make it with regex. Please, help-me writing this regex.

Comment: What is the output that you're expecting?

Comment: Is your list a list of some kind of class? Or is it a list of strings? What is the overall goal? I think you may be going down the wrong path.

Comment: please ignore the highlight, it is a plain text. the class means a regular school class, not the O.O. one. I edit the questions

Comment: What is your delimiter between fields? From your regex it's a `\t`, from example it's a `\r\n`.

Comment: Try [`Teacher\s+(?<teacher>.*)(?:\s*Class\s+(?<class>.+)(?:\s*student\s+(?<student>.+))*)*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Teacher%5cs%2b%28%3f%3cteacher%3e.*%29%28%3f%3a%5cs*Class%5cs%2b%28%3f%3cclass%3e.%2b%29%28%3f%3a%5cs*student%5cs%2b%28%3f%3cstudent%3e.%2b%29%29*%29*&i=Teacher+teacher+name%0d%0aClass+class+name%0d%0astudent+full+name+1%0d%0astudent+full+name+2%0d%0aClass+class+name%0d%0astudent+full+name+1%0d%0astudent+full+name+2%0d%0a&o=m). This will return flat lists of classes, teachers and students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to define a grammar. Consider using [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) or other parsers generator.
However you can do parsing by regex and some extra code in C#

Define your models:

```
public class Teacher
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Class> Classes { get; set; } = new List<Class>();
}

public class Class
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; } = new List<Student>();
}

public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then parse your input:

```
var lineParser = new Regex("^(?<kind>Teacher|Class|)\\s*(?<name>[^$]+)");
var lines = input.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(line =>
    {
        var match = lineParser.Match(line);
        var kind = match.Groups["kind"].Value;
        var name = match.Groups["name"].Value;
        return new { kind, name };
    });

var teachers = new List<Teacher>();
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    if (line.kind == "Teacher")
        teachers.Add(new Teacher {Name = line.name});
    else if (line.kind == "Class")
        teachers.Last().Classes.Add(new Class {Name = line.name});
    else
        teachers.Last().Classes.Last().Students.Add(new Student {Name = line.name});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using following regex:

```
Teacher[ \f\t\v]([^\n\r]+)\r?\n(?:Class[ \f\t\v]([^\n\r]+)\r?\n(?:student[ \f\t\v]([^\n\r]+)\r?\n)*)*
```

You can then use Groups and Captures to find out teachers, classes and students. To match which student goes into which class you will have to examine index of captures and sort them appropriately.